# How to make thorns (Crown of Thorns)?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I’ve downloaded this model of a [Crown of Thorns](https://grabcad.com/library/crown-of-thorns-obj-1), but noticed that it’s got no thorns although the render image had them.

[image: Image of render]

How can I make thorns for this model?

Comment: I suggest you to model it by yourself from scratch. I guess the model from your link doesn't use modifiers so you'll have to model each spike individually. Using @Alois Coissard 's and mine methods'll allow you to create them all automatically and have the better control on the object's shape (thanks to modifiers).

Answer (score 11):

You may create the thorns fast using some ***modifiers***.
[image]

Add two (or more) cylinders and place them next to each other. Model the spikes. Join cylinders with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in *Object Mode*. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to place the cursor in the center, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Origin to 3D Cursor*. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Apply Rot&Scale*. Add a *Bezier Circle* also (*Add*-->*Curve*-->*Circle*).
[image]

Select cylinders and add the ***Subsurf*** and ***Simple Deform*** modifiers. Add some subdivisions in ***Subsurf*** panel. Smooth the object using *smooth shading* in the *Transform* panel of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>). Set the ***Simple Deform*** type to *Twist* and set the angle to *180* degrees (or other value depending on your preferences).
[image]

Next add an ***Array*** modifier. Set its *Z offset* to *1.000*. Check the *Merge* checkbox. Increase the *Count* number. Then add a ***Curve*** modifier and set the *Bezier Circle* as a target.
[image]

Remember of the proper order of the modifiers. This is the key to make it work as it should.
[image]

Finally select the *Bezier Circle* and go to the *Curve* header. Check the *Stretch* and *Bounds Clamp* checkboxes. 
[image]

Try to add more cylinders and randomise the spikes positions and directions for the different results. You may also apply the modifiers (without *Subsurf*) at the end and randomize the size, shape and direction of each spike to make it look more realistic.
[image]

Comment: Oh, it's simplier this way :D. Good job ;).

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a way to make your crown in few steps.

- Create a simple **circle**, and move it in edit mode, according to the pictures.

[image] [image]

- Add a **screw modifier** like this.

[image]

- Create a **Bezier Circle**, add a **curve modifier** to the first circle, and then **select** the Bezier Circle in the modifier panel.

[image]

- **Apply** all the modifiers, and then you can **duplicate** your new object.

[image]

- Now you can extrude some parts of your crown and make the thorns. Don't forget to smooth the vertex, and add a subdivision modifier for a better result.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't thought about using the Screw modifier for this. Nice one!